# Increase the text size on a racket button

Tags: button, text, fonts, size, racket

I am doing some GUI stuff in racket and am playing around with some large buttons. When the buttons size is increased, the text given for the button stays the same size. Is it possible to get the button text size to increase?

Edit

```
(define square
 (new button%
   [parent frame]
   [label ""]
   [min-width 300]
   [min-height 300]
   ))
```

So I have this button that is set to a width and height of 200 x 200. The label is set as empty currently but is changed when the button is pressed.
This sets the button label to X or O depending which player's turn it is who has clicked. However, even though the button is increased in size, the text remains the same size. Is it possible for me to get the label to also increase in size?

Comment: please add some code showing what you are trying to do

Comment: Just made the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set and the alter the style field:
[racket style](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/editor-overview.html#%28part._editorstyles%29)
You can specifically alter font/text size using this in a natural way.

Another hacky/quick option:
Try changing the font field in your [button](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/button_.html), although these are restricted, the different options effect in different font sizes: 
[Racket_Gui_Docs.Fonts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=gui#(part._.Fonts))

Comment: I found a way to do it in the images.rkt racket documentation but it requires 2htdp/image. Which it is not letting me require while also having the gui library and gives me this error "module: identifier already imported from a different source in:
  make-pen
  2htdp/image
  racket/gui/base"

Comment: @FatboyJames I encourage you to **always** try to use basic, natural solutions. Use the built in 'style' field.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would use the style to increase the text size in a button?

Comment: Will do later on

Comment: @FatboyJames I have this test today, I will get back to this ;)

Comment: Don't worry about it, managed to get it to work. However if you know how to change the color of a button without affecting the text label that would be really useful